# GraphQL: Utilizing introspection functionality for data mutation

Tags: graphql, introspection

From my understanding, GraphQL is a great query language for fetching data. However, data mutation, even when using a GraphQL client framework such as Relay, does not seem to be client-side developer friendly. Reason being, they need to know the logic behind the mutation and use it inside the client code.
Would it be better if GraphQL could expose some information to Relay via the introspection functionality, because no other frameworks seem to already be doing this? Also, what would be some of the technical challenges involved building a GraphQL client this way?

Comment: "Reason being, they need to know the logic behind the mutation and use it inside the client code" -- they need to know the logic behind the queries just as much. Introspection makes metadata about operations available for tools (e.g., code completion, syntax validation, code generation). That is all.

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL has chosen to implement mutations in a purely RPC-style model. That is, mutations don't include any metadata about what kinds of changes they are likely to make to the backend. As a contrast, we can look at something like REST, where verbs like POST and PATCH indicate the client's intention about what should happen on the backend.

There are pros and cons to this. On the one hand, it's more convenient to write client code if your framework can learn to incorporate changes automatically, however I would claim this is not possible in all but the most principled of REST APIs. On the other hand, the RPC model has a huge advantage in that the server is not limited in the kinds of operations it can perform. Rather than needing to describe modifications in terms of updates to particular objects, you can simply define any semantic operation you like as long as you can write the server code.

#### Is this consistent with the rest of GraphQL?

I believe that the current implementation of mutations is consistent with the data fetching part of GraphQL's design, which has a similar concept: Any field on any object could be computed from the others, meaning that there is no stable concept of an "object" in the output of a query. So in order to have mutations which automatically update the results from a query, you would need to take into account computed fields, arguments, aggregates, etc. GraphQL as currently specified seems to explicitly make the trade off that it's fine for the information transfer from the server to be lossy, in order to enable complete flexibility in the implementation of server-side fields.

#### Are there some mutations that can be incorporated automatically?

Yes. In particular, if your mutation return values incorporate the same object types as your queries, a smart GraphQL client such as Apollo Client will merge those results into the cache without any extra work. By using fragments and picking convenient return types for mutations, you can get by with this approach for most or all mutations:

```
fragment PostDetails {
  id
  score
  title
}

query PostWithDetails {
  post(id: 5) {
    ...PostDetails
  }
}

mutation UpdatePostTitle {
  updatePostTitle(id: 5, newTitle: "Great new title") {
    ...PostDetails
  }
}
```

The place where things get tricky are for mutations that are inserting and deleting objects, since it's not immediately clear what the client should do with that mutation result.

#### Can this be improved on with introspection or otherwise?

I think it would be very advantageous to have a restricted model for mutations that works more automatically, if the ability to upgrade to a more flexible approach is preserved.

One particular example would be to have a semantic way to declare "delete" mutations:

```
type Mutation {
  deletePost(id: ID!): DeletePostResult @deletes
}
```

If a client can read the directives on these mutation fields via introspection, then it could identify the `deletes` directive and guess that the `id` field represents an object that was deleted and should be purged from the cache.

I'm one of the core contributors to Apollo, and I think it would be quite easy to experiment with features like this in companion packages. We had some inklings of this in core as well, and intentionally designed the store format to make things like this possible.

#### TL;DR

The current approach makes GraphQL super flexible and is consistent with the rest of the design, but it would be interesting to add conventions to make some mutations automatic.